Have the security defaults changed under Spring Security 6?
Our organization is doing massive updates to all our Java apps.   We are moving from Spring 5 to Spring 6 and Java 8 to Java 17 at the same time.
One of our web apps which was "open" under Spring Security 5 has suddenly started asking for a username and password.   Did the Spring Security defaults (such as "authorization/no authorization") change in the move from 5 to 6?
This is new territory for me, so I am flying pretty blind.   I am not expecting anyone to "fix" this problem for me, just a simple "check this page" would be fine.

Yes, spring-security 6 is secure by default, i.e., it denies all requests to resources that have not been explicitly given the permission to.

In Spring Security 5.8 and earlier, requests with no authorization rule are permitted by default. It is a stronger security position to deny by default, thus requiring that authorization rules be clearly defined for every endpoint. As such, in 6.0, Spring Security by default denies any request that is missing an authorization rule.

See (or: "check this page"):

See: File download fails after SpringBoot Update (from 2.5 to 3.2)
Ensure all messages have defined authorization rules
Preparing for 6.0


Thank you.   That precisely explains the behavior we have been seeing.
